# How to decrement from an object that's holding a value?

Tags: python, list, subtraction

I don't know how to decrement from an object in a list.

For example:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
lst = [a, b, c]
choice = a
choice = choice - 2
```

When I do that it doesn't deduct from `a`

Comment: There is a deep misunderstanding of what variables in Python represent. I can fully understand this wrong approach, as I, coming from other programming languages, also had initially problems with the Python concept that the variable name is just a reference to the object. You can read up on this, for instance, [here](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: @Mr.T true it gets confusing sometimes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use indexing to access list elements:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
list = [a, b, c]
choice = 0 # the index of `a`
lst[choice] -= 2
```

This won't change the value of `a` because integers are immutable in python. Only the reference stored in the list will change.

You can find the index by value using `list.index`:

```
choice = lst.index(a)
```

If you want to search by name instead of by value, use a dictionary instead of a list:

```
d = {
    'a' = 1,
    'b' = 2,
    'c' = 3
}
d['a'] -= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question in that it prompts us to think about the meaning of 'object'.

For example, here is some code that would manipulate 'objects' in the way I think you were expecting:

```py
a = [1]
b = [2]
c = [3]
lst = [a, b, c]
index_choice = 6 % 3 # some calculation that results in 0
choice = lst[index_choice]
choice[0] = choice[0] - 2
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[-1]
```

Here we initialize `a`, `b` and `c` to be references to mutable objects (lists of length one, in this case), and we initialize `lst` to be a collection of these object references.

We then decide we want to update an object at a certain position `index_choice` in `lst` (let's say it's position 0, since that's where the object referenced by `a` is). We put a reference to that object in a variable named `choice` with the statement `choice = lst[index_choice]`.

We then modify the value of an attribute of the object: in this case, the element at index 0, which is the lone number in the list of length one that is referenced by `choice`. We modify this attribute using the assignment `choice[0] = choice[0] - 2`.

Now we examine `a`, and we see that the value of its `attribute` (the lone number in the list of length one that is referenced by `a`) has been updated from `1` to `-1`. This is because `choice` and `a` are different references to the same object, namely the list that was initialized to `[1]` and that we updated with the statement `choice[0] = choice[0] - 2`.

In summary, what I believe you were expecting to happen with `objects` can indeed be achieved in Python, but it requires that the objects (or more specifically, the objects' attributes) be modified in place, something that is not possible with immutable types such as integer but IS possible with objects of a mutable type such as list or a user-defined type.